# Create Notifications with the Actor as the Application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

With a `Notification` model, how would you model the Sender/Actor relationship to allow for system notifications, where the application is the sender? i.e "Your export completed" or "Your trial is about to end".

Here is an explanation for some of the fields for the above model:

> `recipient_id`: Represents the user in your application which will
>   receive the notification.
>
> `actor_id`: Represents the user in your application which triggered
>   the notification.
>
> `read_at`: The time when the notification was read.
>   A value of nil is used for unread notifications.
>
> `notifiable_id`: The object that represents this notification (a post,
>   comment, etc). This will be a polymorphic association.
>
> `notifiable_type`: Type of the notifiable object. This is usually
>   represented by a humanized (and optionally, internationalized) string
>   form of the object's class.

My first thought was to make the Actor(able) polymorphic, but that wouldn't allow for a DEFAULT_APPLICATION that references the application, because it's not in the database and therefore not referable. Extending on the idea of making the Actor polymorphic, the actor could be the `@export` and `current_user.subscription`, respectively. A third option would be to model the `Notification` to allow for a `nil` Actor and leave the actor `nil`.

```
# Your export completed. Download your export.
# Your trial is ending soon. Update your payment information.
Notification.create(recipient: current_user, actor: ?, action: "completed", notifiable: @export)
Notification.create(recipient: current_user, actor: ?, action: "ending", notifiable: current_user.subscription)

# Polymorphic Actor
Notification.create(recipient: current_user, actor: @export, action: "completed", notifiable: @export)
Notification.create(recipient: current_user, actor: current_user.subscription, action: "ending", notifiable: current_user.subscription)

# nil
Notification.create(recipient: current_user, actor: nil, action: "completed", notifiable: @export)
Notification.create(recipient: current_user, actor: nil, action: "ending", notifiable: current_user.subscription)
```

Comment: At a recent job we handled this issue by allowing nil actor, but actually it's a better idea to make actor polymorphic, so you can identify _where_ in the system it originated from. However, it might not be typical polymorphism, if not all the "actors" represent database records. So you might have to write some special kind of polymorphism code, it all depends on your needs. This question is a little broad though, maybe you could show your attempt rather than talking about it in the abstract

Comment: I'm trying to future-proof the idea of Notifications as I go about the implementation now; in the scenario where the Actor becomes polymorphic, and the target that is `notifiable` also becomes the `Actor` seems to be an OK approach. Off the top of my head I can't think of situations where the Actor wouldn't be present. I don't have much more to show code-wise than what I've put above, but the discussion is helpful Max.